# Carb, fat and protein changes in vegetable fermentation, specifically a ballpark reduction arc in carbohydrates

Tags: fermentation, nutrient-composition

I have been fermenting vegetables, kimchi for the most part, for a few years and am familiar with the general arc of the process, as well as observing how active my ferment is.

Yesterday, I started a half gallon of sauerkraut, a half gallon of white kimchi, and a couple pints of fermented beets. Today, I am working up nutritional values for each in support of a Keto eating plan. I've had no trouble working up the raw calories, fat, net carbs and protein for each recipe. Yet I know that fermenting will change the carbohydrates and perhaps other values.

I am aware there is no one-size-fits-all for this calculation, rather the opposite, it seems the number of variables is too broad to pin down any kind of equation. Case in point, I have three ferments going, all burning at a different pace. That said, I'm looking for any kind of rough approximation based on experience.

Two facts seem certain. One, that the fermented product will have a lower carbohydrate value than the cumulative raw ingredients. And two, the resulting carbohydrates will never reach zero. That leaves the rate of burn. **Based on your experience, what would you expect the carbohydrate burn to be in a highly active ferment for something like Napa Cabbage, Red Cabbage, or Beets?**

Less important, but of keen interest, should I expect the other values (cals, fat, or protein) to change as the result of fermentation?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SA! Have a look at the [tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) when you get a chance. Just so you're aware, questions on health effects of food are generally [off-topic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). That is not to say your question (which I think is interesting) is, though.

Comment: I agree this is on-topic as it is about chemical changes to food as part of a cooking process and not about benefits.

Comment: @LSchoon you may want to look at the nutrient composition tag. I know this is weird, because it is an exemption from an exemption :) but we basically allow questions on how a named nutrient changes during cooking. The separation line is: If the question requires the answers to make judgements on what is healthy (e.g. the question is "which good things disappear during fermentation" and by answering "X disappears", the answerer has implicitly declared X to be a healthy substance) it is off topic. If the OP has set a measurable goal for their food composition, and the reason for that was...

Comment: ... their personal health belief, we take the question - because we don't have to tell them what is healthy, just how to achieve a certain objective state of their food which they happen to believe is healthy. We do prune discussion on whether the belief is founded or not, though, and just focus on the literal question.

Comment: @rumtscho I think you may have misunderstood my (perhaps poorly worded) comment. I did not mean to suggest this question should be closed as being about health, but was trying to make the same point as you in reaction to some close votes having appeared on this question.

Comment: @LSchoon oh, thanks! I indeed misread your comment - I thought you were saying that the question is off topic, but interesting. I'll leave the comment exchange here, if you don't mind, because it is a fine point of which other users are also frequently not aware.

Comment: @rumtscho [No problem](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/001/496/828/df5.jpg)!

Comment: Thank you @LSchoon, I appreciate your greeting and your advice. Would it be appropriate to offer my own solution in the form of an "answer" and solicit the community for confirmation/feedback concerning the proposed solution?

Comment: @BuffaloRabor [Answering your own question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is encouraged! An answer should be an *answer*, though: if it is a follow-up question, you should ask that as a separate question. If it is an 'update' to the current question, you can always [edit](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/109553/edit) your question.

Answer (score 2):

on the "Less important, but of keen interest" question:

let's talk carbs instead of cals here.  cals are potential chemical energy stored in carbohydrates, fats, proteins, etc.  in vegetable fermentation, the fat and protein content is not a significant contributor to potential calories, so i'll confine this to carbohydrates

microbial fermenters' (effective, not comprehensive or quantitative) ...

most who do this don't track a carb burn rate, but they definitely notice when the jars quit bubbling.  CO2 output rate is directly proportional to carb burn rate, but those are very difficult to measure without specialized equipment

there are two ways that fermenting usually stops, when fermenters

- run out of food (mostly carbs)
- byproducts (here, lactic acid) are concentrated enough to halt reproduction

so if the jar's quit bubbling, it's important to understand that it might not be down to near zero carbs

inputs are

- carbs
- minuscule amounts of protein and trace minerals

outputs are

- more fermenters
- carbon dioxide, which is not retained by most canners
- lactic acid
- compounds that lend funk to flavor and aroma

note that fermenters consist mostly of:  water, lipids (structural and energy storage), and protein (structural and information storage)

to answer the keen interest ...

- net change in carbs?  yes.  down
- net change in protein?  yes.  up, but not by much
- net change in fat/lipids?  yes.  up, but not by much

Comment: @pleasepassthechese is it safe to say calories are consumed "in proportion" to the consumption of net carbohydrates during fermentation?

Comment: yes, it's safe to say that